# Linux to Windows SCP password-less access

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, scp

I have a raspberry pi running Linux (Jessie) which takes pictures every hour and is supposed to upload it onto a windows server. I want to set up a password-less SSH access so that I can upload pictures from the raspberry pi to the windows using SCP. Most of the tutorials online deal with copying files from Linux to Linux environments or windows to Linux set-ups. How do I set up password-less access FROM Raspberry pi to Windows? Should I generate key pairs on windows or raspberry pi? I am also having confusion as to where does the public/private keys resides (windows server or Linux client)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score -1):

You may install Cygwin on the Windows side, then you will get the environment similar to Linux on Windows. The keys can be generated on the Linux side and copied to the Windows, location is the same as in the Linux (/.ssh).

There are several tutorials on Cygwin with private key authentication, like this one: https://dbaportal.eu/2015/03/06/setup-openssh-cygwin-for-public-key-authentication/

Note that you will probably have to set up proper access rights for .ssh directory in Windows. You may use chmod in the same way as on Linux, set 700 for .ssh directory and 600 for authorized_keys.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do not have the option to install any other software on the windows PC